# GetRequest to Jenkins with basic auth

Tags: c#, api, jenkins, get

I am trying to write simple get request to Jenkins to receive crumb issuer. I need it to run Jenkins job remotely.

Here is my code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://jenkins/crumbIssuer/api/json");
WebRequest http = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://jenkins/crumbIssuer/api/json");
http.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(
     new Uri("http://jenkins/crumbIssuer/api/json"),
     "NTLM",
     new NetworkCredential("user", "pass"));
http.Credentials = cc;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

I received:

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'
```

What is my mistake?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for that, I have found the solution already.

FYI: http://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/.

Check the link and there the chapter: C# HttpClient Basic authentication